# How to get a specific item from JSON

Tags: node.js, json, dialogflow-es, dynamodb-queries

I'm new to node.js and DialogFlow. I am using DynamoDB to store data and I'm creating skills on Google. I'm trying to write a code to retrieve a specific item on that table.

I've got it working to show all items where ID is equal = 1, but how would I make it so I can just get attribute 'name'?

My idea is a user provides an id then the code will retrieve name where id was 1 and store that as a variable and use `agent.add('hello $(name)');` to display it back as speech to the user.

```
  function readdata(agent){
    let dbread = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    const id = agent.parameters.id;

    let read = function(){
        var parameters = {
            TableName:"Dynamodb",
            Key:{
                "id":id
            }
        };
        dbread.get(parameters, function(err,data){
            if(err){
                console.log("error",JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
            }else{
                console.log("success",JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
            }
        });
      agent.add(`hello ${name}`);
    };
    read();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the data back from the `get()` call, the `data` object will [contain an `Item` attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property). The value of this attribute will be another object that contains the attribute/value pairs for this record, or be empty if the record isn't found.

The debugging you have in place that shows `JSON.stringify(data)` should show this.

Assuming you knew all the fields were there, you could do something like

```
const name = data.Item.name;
```

a more robust way using current JavaScript would be to make sure everything was assigned, otherwise return `undefined` at any point. So something like this would work

```
const name = data && data.Item && data.Item.name;
```

**However - you will have a problem doing this with Dialogflow**

You don't show which Dialogflow library you're using, but most of them require you to return a Promise to indicate that it needs to wait for asynchronous calls (such as the call to DynamoDB) to complete. You're using `get()` with a callback function instead of a Promise. So you need to do one of the following:

1. Wrap the call in a Promise
2. Since `get()` returns an [AWS.Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) you can use the `promise()` method of this to get a Promise that you can return and which has `then` portions that generate the response - similar to how you're doing your callbacks now.

Under this scheme, your call might look something like this (untested):

```
    return dbread.get(parameters).promise()
      .then( data => {
        console.log("success",JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
        const name = data && data.Item && data.Item.name;
        if( name ){
          agent.add( `Hello ${name}` );
        } else {
          agent.add( "I don't know who you are." );
        }
      })
      .catch( err => {
        console.log("error",JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
        agent.add( "There was an error" );
      });
```